# Does karate use interpreter or complier to run the feature file based code?

Tags: karate

I had the following questions:

1. Does karate use an Interpreter or compiler, exactly how does the feature file code work?
2. Is there an alternate way to write a Junit test using java/js using karate API? or the only way is feature file?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The Feature file is interpreted at run time, and control is given to Java code. Refer to the [source code](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/v1.1.0/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/ScenarioActions.java) for the details.
2. Yes, refer to the [Java API](https://github.com/intuit/karate#java-api) but also pay attention to the pros and cons. Here is an example: [`JavaApiRunner.java`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/v1.1.0/karate-e2e-tests/src/test/java/driver/JavaApiRunner.java).